# Unable to hit breakpoint on AuthorizeAttribute class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Can anyone tell me why I am not able to a breakpoint on a new class I created that is supposed to handle WebApi post requests? Below is my code for the new class and the method that is decorated with the classes attribute

```
namespace MercuryUserWeb.Core.Authorization {

public class ClientUserApi : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        WebRequestState webRequestState = ContainerHome.Container.Resolve<WebRequestState>();
        ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        if (actionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(StaffUserAuthorizeAttribute), true))
            return;

        if (!webRequestState.IsAuthenticated || webRequestState.ClientUser == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            return;         // 401, always show log-in page
        }            
    }
  }  
}
```

**Controller action**

```
namespace MercuryUserWeb.Areas.JApi.Controllers{
[ClientUserApi]
    public class ClientViewController: ApiController, IJApiController
    {           

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [ClientUserApi]
    public ActionResult assignViews(ClientViewModel model)
    {
        string[] clientViewIdsArray = model.selectedViewsForClient.Split(',');
        IEnumerable<long> parsedClientViewIdArray = clientViewIdsArray.Select(long.Parse);
        List<long> clientViewsIdList = parsedClientViewIdArray.ToList();

        string[] volPoolIdArray = model.volPoolIds.Split(',');
        IEnumerable<long> parsedIdArray = volPoolIdArray.Select(long.Parse);
        List<long> volPoolIdList = parsedIdArray.ToList();

        var clientId = clientApiPrincipal.ClientUser.ClientId;

        clientViewService.assignViews(clientViewsIdList, volPoolIdList, clientId);

        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the override keyword. Else you are hiding the virtual implementation of OnAuthorization in AuthorizeAttribute.

```
public class ClientUserApi : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        WebRequestState webRequestState = ContainerHome.Container.Resolve<WebRequestState>();
        ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        if (actionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(StaffUserAuthorizeAttribute), true))
            return;

        if (!webRequestState.IsAuthenticated || webRequestState.ClientUser == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            return;         // 401, always show log-in page
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Although I am still getting a null value for the WebRequestState. Not sure why....